# Shimano Deore FD-M590 replacement

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur

I need a new front derailleur.  I have a Shimano Deore FD-M590, but am rather disappointed in it.  It's only three years old and won't advance the chain to the biggest ring.  Bike shop guy said I need a new one.  I'm never had a derailler go bad that fast.  Does anyone have a suggestion for a replacement.

Comment: I'd be inclined to fiddle with the existing FD some more.  Is it bent?   Can you get the chain to move up if you pull the inner cable by hand?  Have you tried turning the high bump stop a bit?

Comment: Is it damaged or worn out? I find it hard to imagine a worn out FD after 3 years, and would expect the rest of the drive train being replaced several times over before the FD was causing major issues. FD performance is as affected by crank, chain ring and frame quality, so a new FD may not fix the issue.

Comment: No damage that I can see.  I've tried all the adjustments.  I removed it, cleaned and degreased it.  Cables and housing are ok.  It won't move up if I pull the cable by hand.  I've used the same bike guy for years, so I trust him when he said it's done.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adjusting it yourself? http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment

Did you rule out the shifter/cable/cable housing causing problems? Try manipulating the cable tension by hand to shift it to see if this is the case and then work from the problem if it doesn't let you move the cage with reasonable cable manipulation.

If it doesn't adjust and the shifter is good, I'd just replace it with the same thing that is already on there (note that you need to get the right clamp and cable pull type for your frame, so you might as well order it from the bike shop if you don't know what clamp type and what not you need).

FD's are relatively simple parts that don't have a wide range of performance between grades, and its just about as cheap for what you have as with the lower group parts.